# MySQL query using group by clause returns more rows than without it

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Without group by clause, only 1 record returned; with, desired numbers of record returned

```
SELECT 
PM.id AS id, PM.email AS email, PM.name AS name, PM.mobile AS mobile, 
PM.country AS country, PM.status AS status, PM.cdate AS joined_date, 
PM.details_status AS details_status, PM.freeze AS freeze, PM.blacklist AS blacklist, 
PM.blacklist_remark AS blacklist_remark, PM.blacklist_adate AS blacklist_adate, 
MA.m_app_id AS app_id, MA.full_name AS replace_name, MAX(MA.ldate) AS ldate, 
MA.service_type AS svc_type 

FROM whatever_db.tw_person_merchant PM 
    LEFT JOIN (
        whatever_db.tw_person_merchant PMM
        INNER JOIN
        whatever_db.tw_merchant_application_details MA 
        ON PMM.app_id = MA.m_app_id
        INNER JOIN 
        whatever_db.tw_merchant_application MAP 
        ON MA.m_app_id = MAP.id
        AND MAP.status NOT IN ('10' , '60')
        AND MA.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM whatever_db.tw_merchant_application_details WHERE m_app_id = PMM.app_id )
    )  ON PM.app_id = MA.m_app_id 

WHERE PM.details_status IN ('90', '0')
AND PM.blacklist = 0 
AND PM.name != ''

-- **here, without the group by clause, the result is just 1 record
GROUP BY PM.id 
ORDER BY PM.id DESC
```

I was testing the sql script to have relevant merchant returned but in the middle it just show 1 record, after trial and error, the inserted "group by" solve it. But this "group by" is not summarizing but show more results than without it. Unexpected result and such a betrayal of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY`, the query result has one row for each distinct value of the `GROUP BY` expressions. In your case, one row for each value of `PM.id`. Results of aggregate functions like `MAX()` will be applied to the subset of rows in each of the groups associated with the given value.

If you don't use `GROUP BY`, the result is effectively one group, and therefore the query returns just one row. Any aggregate functions are applied to the whole set of rows.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html includes this sentence deep in that long page:

> If no `GROUP BY` is present, all rows implicitly form a single aggregate group.